# How to get list of file on FTP with D?

Tags: ftp, d

I need to get list of files on FTP. I wrote next code, but it's crash at startup.

```
void main()
{
string ftpserver = "myftpserver";
string ftplogin = "username";
string ftppass = "pass";

    auto ftp = FTP(ftpserver);
    ftp.verbose(1);
    ftp.setAuthentication(ftplogin, ftppass);
    ftp.addCommand("LIST");
    ftp.perform();
}
```

The problem with addCommand, because if remove it App start, show FTP root dir and then exit.

Ok. Command sended but how to get result of it? addCommand have type void.

P.S. And I can't understand why after connecting it's immediately exit?

Comment: Side note: `ftp` is a leftover from the 70th. It offers no means of safety whatsoever and is a nightmare for all network admins. If possible try to use a more modern replacement: `sftp`, `scp` or `ftps` where at least the communication channel is encrypted, though not your data.

Comment: I know, but I need to get data from old stupid FTP :(

Comment: So you want to invest _even more time, effort and money_ into a solution you see as outdated yourself? Why not make the step and publish the content with a better server _in parallel_? Costs nothing, allows step by step migration and protects your data.

Comment: @arkascha The choice to use FTP may be out of Suliman's hands. Whether or not they should be using it, FTP support is in the D standard library and this is a valid question.

Comment: @MattKline Certainly this is a valid question, I never claimed otherwise! I just gave a side note, that's all. I did so because in my experience it very often pays out to think out of the box. Very often people forget to question existing situations, try to fit in when it would make much more sense to change the situation. Sometimes this is indeed not possible. but I found that more often it is, and typically it is much easier than expected.

Comment: @arkascha I do not have access for remote server, but I need to grab data from it...
btw, all shared hosting that I know provide FTP only access

Comment: I looked at sftp and analogs. They are look like addons on FTP, but not new protocols...

Comment: @user1432751 Did you ask the one responsible for that service if it is possible to offer a more modern protocol in parallel with ftp? Anything speaking against it?

Comment: @user1432751 About sftp and scp: they appear familiar, that is exactly because they try to be usable the same as ftp whilst finally getting rid of the shortcomings of ftp. But they are completely independent, actually a completely different protocol: it is an ssh server, not a ftp server they rely on. The only exception here is ftps: that indeed is an extension of some ftp servers. sftp works exactly like ftp, the only difference is that the control channel offers string encryption (read: no plain text passwords though the internet).

Comment: @user1432751 sorry, I just saw that I made a typo: the last sentence in my last comment must read: "ftps works exactly like ftp, the only difference is ..." Compared to that sftp and the like encrypt _all_ traffic and they use only a single socket / port instead of the insane armada of connections required by ftp. Sorry for this confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `addCommand()` from "LIST" (not a valid FTP command) to either "LS" or "ls" (they behave differently on some sites).

I'm not sure about all of the `D` bindings for `curl` - you can normally get the results of `perform()` by calling `curl_getinfo()`.  I know `D` does at least have bindings for these:

```
CURLcode  curl_easy_perform(CURL *curl);
CURLcode  curl_easy_getinfo(CURL *curl, CURLINFO info,...);
```

which may be a better alternative, anyway, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `ftp.perform`, OK not with method itself, because as frasnian said problem is with `LIST` command. But if you look on [documentation](http://dlang.org/phobos-prerelease/std_net_curl.html#.FTP) to method `perform` you should see `ThrowOnError throwOnError` as a first parameter of this method. So you can make it nothrow or put it into `try catch` block.

But this still doesn`t fix your problem with bad command.

Comment: I tried various varuants of list command. The result is same:
```< 500 Unknown command.
* QUOT string not accepted: ls```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, `LIST` is not a valid FTP command. You can find a list of valid commands [here](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/ftp.html).

Also, before calling `perform`, you should set a callback that receives incoming data with [onReceive](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html#.FTP.onReceive). That callback can accumulate the results into a string or whatever else you want to do with them.

Comment: Could you show me how to use delegates or explain how they are work. I read about it, but not sure how they should work in real code...

Comment: ftp.onReceive = (ubyte[] data) {return data;};

Error: function std.net.curl.FTP.Protocol!().onReceive (uint delegate(ubyte[]) callback) is not callable using argument types (ubyte[] function(ubyte [] data) pure nothrow @nogc @safe)

What's wrong?